# Enable Drupal 8 theme on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to dockerize **Drupal 8**. One thing which I couldn't wrap my head around is making customizations available to new containers. For instance, I have downloaded Bootstrap theme in my dockerfile and it shows under **Appearance > Uninstalled themes**. And I can Install and set it as default from admin UI.
However, I don't want my docker image/container users to deal with this instead it should be installed by default when they run the container.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM drupal:8.9.13
RUN cd /opt/drupal/ \
    && composer require drupal/bootstrap:^3.23 \
    && composer install \ 
    && chown www-data:www-data -R /opt/drupal/web/themes
```

P.S. I'm new to Drupal workloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can add drush via composer inside your docker file: `composer require --dev drush/drush` and call drush bin using its vendor dir `./vendor/bin/drush command`. Now to set the default theme use the following command: `./vendor/bin/drush config-set system.theme default bootstrap`.

The optional things that could be done are also `./vendor/bin/drush en bootstrap` and `./vendor/bin/drush cr` - to clear the cache if the theme default theme won't show at first time. You have to check if it's needed.

Credits go to: [1](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/install-drush-using-composer?p=1156) and [2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200771/how-do-i-change-the-default-theme-with-drush-master/200779)

Comment: I tried as suggested i.e. updated my dockerfile to install drush via composer and enable theme via drush but getting this error: *"Command **config:set** was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As a result, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with --debug to see relevant log messages."*. The line in Dockerfile which complains is:

`RUN vendor/bin/drush config:set system.theme default bootstrap`

Comment: config-set not config:set ?

Comment: I tried both the options but same error. Referred [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/extend-theme-install.html#s-using-drush-to-install-a-theme) for syntax

Comment: Sam check the drush version. Maybe this command is for the older ver.

Answer (score 0):

Installing modules with composer is very different from installing them in Drupal.  In order to install a module in Drupal you need access to the database with a working installation.  The problem is that anything in the Dockerfile is part of the build process - which is used for creating an image that is finally run via CMD.  Now, I'm not familiar with the official Drupal Docker image but I'm sure it must be a simple PHP based container?  The point being is that the last thing to happen is for PHP to actually be run, and until that point, MySQL is not running.

How to achieve what you desire very much depends on how you install Drupal after Docker has finished building?  Ideally, you're doing this with an ENTRYPOINT script rather than manually - and if so, then after the install - enable the theme with Drush there.  Ideally, you should just make your own distribution profile and this would enable the theme for the user on site-install (and allow you to make all your customisations in one place).

On the other hand, if part of what you're doing is scripted - then you probably just need to add a Drush alias so Drush is able to locate your installation when a command is run outside of webroot; see https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.site.yml but you haven't said how you're installing Drupal so I can't say for sure.

Comment: That’s another piece of the puzzle I need to solve. Currently, when I run  this docker image, it launches drupal installation wizard via install.php which I am looking to avoid. Container being ephemeral and stateless, I want my drupal website to appear with new container run command instead of this manual install page. Can you point me in right direction and with a sample if possible?

Comment: If drush would be available inside container (try to make it globally available) then I would use `drush si` command with the certain variables.

Comment: There are three ways; 1. most mysql containers allow you to provide a database dump which is automatically imported once the instance is running. 2. add a drush si in the ENTRYPOINT script, or 3. which TBH, is most preferable as the other two take time (where the install is unstable until it’s finished). Is to just make a Drupal distribution profile, and allow your user to choose it themselves and install Drupal in the UI

Comment: So with option#3, if the container restarts or if a new container is added (scale-out), user is again presented with install screen but this time there will be a custom profile option to chose from? Correct? Is this you are recommending?

Comment: It's up to you?  It really depends on your requirements.  The "problem" with 1 and 2 is that they're not instant, and worse still ... the commands run _invisibly_ so an end-user will have no idea what's happening behind the scenes.  You could perhaps have a "holding page" which your ENTRYPOINT switches off ... but well ... that's also a bit rubbish...  So yes, when you make a Drupal distribution profile -  it appears in the list of installable profile and a user can then select it e.g. https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/installation-profile-demo.png

Comment: I have started with custom profile option. Now, when I start my containers, I see "Modules installing" step first and then "Configure site" step of the Admin UI. I have already configured my site in my container#1 hence I don't want to repeat the same steps in container#2. How can I avoid this from showing with every new container and instead re-use the site information from the first time or somehow embed this in Profile?

Comment: All steps are alterable and/ or removable.  I don't remember if you said which version of Drupal this is for, but all versions of this hook are linked to under "Same name and namespace in other branches" https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks_alter/7.x (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.core.inc/function/install_tasks/7.x for the list, or the incredibly hard to find documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-7-installation-profile)